# How do I increase a drone's Response?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun

One of the players in my group just lost all his PC's drones in one combat turn. Is there a way to increase their Response or make them less squishy?

Comment: It's way to broad to improve on something we don't know. This *might* be a good question if you had a specific drone and specific requirements and constraints.